# kdeplot() got multiple values for argument 'data'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, kdeplot

help me to solve this problem

```
sns.kdeplot('Age', data=data, ax=ax1, shade=True, color='grey', alpha=1)
ax1.set_xlabel('Age', {'fontsize':16,'fontweight':'bold', 'color':'black'})
```

error message

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-db0457e96e67> in <cell line: 25>()
     23 
     24 #-------Ax 1------------------------------------------------
---> 25 sns.kdeplot('Age', data=data, ax=ax1, shade=True, color='grey', alpha=1)
     26 ax1.set_xlabel('Age', {'fontsize':16,'fontweight':'bold', 'color':'black'})
     27 

TypeError: kdeplot() got multiple values for argument 'data'
```

i've read the same problem, but i don't know in my code doesn't works

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, when you [edit] the question, add the "python" tag.